# Could not resolve mscorlib for target framework '.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2'.In VisualStudio 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I am using Visual Studio 2019. I had been using this for past 1 week without any trouble. But from yesterday onwards after an update done for Visual Studio, while opening Designer page, it's showing error:

> Could not resolve mscorlib for target framework '.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2'. This can happen if the target framework is not installed or if the framework moniker is incorrectly formatted.

[image]

Comment: Is that version installed? Have you tried changing it? Or have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

I solved that with elevated prompt command:

sfc /scannow

Answer (score -2):

you should open the properties of the project, in item of 'Application', refresh the 'target framework':

[Where to open and refresh the target framework](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jcsry.png)

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.